# Error en Listbox, 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert' , Python

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

Buen dia, No logro resolver el error que me manda con el codigo. Me marca el `insert`, Pero no entiendo el porque.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import * 


def agrega():
   lstmaterias.insert(END,entrada.get())

ventana = tkinter.Tk()
ventana.geometry("600x500")

lstmaterias = Listbox(ventana,width=50).place(x=100,y=120)

entrada=StringVar()
txtanime=Entry(ventana,textvariable=entrada).place(x=150,y=20)    
boton = tkinter.Button(ventana, text="Compila pls",command=agrega, width="20", height="2", bg="#00CD63")
boton.place(x=300,y=20)
ventana.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yo tengo entendido que no puedes hacer esto cuando metes un widget en una variable

```
lstmaterias = Listbox(ventana,width=50).place(x=100,y=120)
```

tienes que hacerlo de esta manera

```
lstmaterias = Listbox(ventana,width=50)
lstmaterias.place(x=100,y=120)
```

y de la misma forma con todos los widgets que metes en una variable

de esta forma si se puede hacer lo que tu haces y te funcionaria.

```
Listbox(ventana,width=50).place(x=100,y=120)
```

espero te pueda servir.